# Why is href not working on local site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, permissions

I want to add a new link directing to a local html website to a menu list on a website. The main website is in aspx but I'm working on the html copy. The referenced link points to a html website on my local machine.

```
<li><a href="C:/Users/User/Desktop/Consulting.html"><b>Custom Solutions</b><br />
Custom Software Applications and Solutions</a></li>
```

If I replace the href with www.google.com , the link point well to google. But it does not work for the local website. `C:/Users/User/Desktop/Consulting.html` is a downloaded website from an aspx site.

Is the href not working because of denied permissions or because the local website is from an aspx website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Consulting.html"></a>
```

and it will only work if the HTML file you are viewing is on your local machine.

Comment: I changed the href, and it is still not working. I click the link and nothing happens. It's like it is ignoring my click command.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<li><a href="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Consulting.html"><b>Custom Solutions</b><br />
Custom Software Applications and Solutions</a></li>
```